# Accessing Java files within .tar files using Java

Tags: java, file, tar

I am creating a Java application that will take in .tar files and retrieve all the files from these .tar files. I know you can use `GZIPInputStream` to get the files from the .tar files, but is it possible to get these files from the `GZIPInputStream` as a `FileInputStream`, something like below?

```
InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible due to the CTOR of GZipInputStream that lets you accept an InputStream as parameter (GZipInputStream is a wrapper in that sense to InputStream). Then all you need to do is follow examples you can find on the internet such as [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) in order to extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

`GZIPInputStream` extends `InputStream` (not directly) so in my opinion it's ok. Try this:

```
InputStream in = new java.util.GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while (( read = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
{
     // do sth
}
```